# How to pass X-Config-Token with spring-cloud-starter-config

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-vault-config

It works fine when I invoke the config server using curl -X GET http://localhost:8888/limits-service/dev -H "X-Config-Token: s.6S92v3OekCYEAWjp8unbt4ei"

But from the client microservice, upon invoking the config service http://localhost:8888/limits-service/dev how to pass the header. The following details are configured in the client microservice application.properties but gets 404 error.

```
spring.application.name=limits-service
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888/
spring.profiles.active=dev.
```

So how to pass X-Config-Token: s.6S92v3OekCYEAWjp8unbt4ei ?

Answer (score 2):

This token can be provided within the client by setting spring.cloud.config.token in `bootstrap.yml`.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      token: YourVaultToken
```